# What is difference between Fully Connected layer and Bilinear layer in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision

What is the difference between `Fully Connected` layers and `Bilinear` layers in deep learning?

Answer (score 8):

I quote the answers from [What is a bilinear tensor layer (in contrast to a standard linear neural network layer) or how can I imagine it?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-bilinear-tensor-layer-in-contrast-to-a-standard-linear-neural-network-layer-or-how-can-I-imagine-it).

*A bilinear function is a function of two inputs $x$ and $y$ that is linear in each input separately. Simple bilinear functions on vectors are the dot product or the element-wise product.*

*Let $M$ be a matrix. The function $f(x,y)=x^TMy=\sum_iM_{ij}x_iy_j$ is bilinear in $x$ and $y$. In fact, any scalar bilinear function on two vectors takes this form. Note that a bilinear function is a linear combination of $x_iy_j$ whereas a linear function such as $g(x,y)=Ax+By$ can only have $x_i$ or $y_i$. For neural nets, that means a bilinear function allows for richer interactions between inputs.*

*Now what if you want a bilinear function that outputs a vector? Well, you simply define a matrix $M_k$ for each coordinate of the output and you end up with a stack of matrices. That stack of matrices is called a tensor (3-mode tensor to be exact). You can imagine the bilinear tensor product with two vectors as $x^⊤M_ky$ computed on each “slice” of the tensor.*

Bilinear Models *consists of two feature extractors whose outputs
are multiplied using an outer product at each location of the image
and pooled to obtain an image descriptor. [1](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eskong2/img/CVgourp_20160120.pdf)*

[image]

Its advantage is that *it can model pairwise feature interactions in a translationally invariant manner, which is particularly useful for fine-grained categorization. It also allows end-to-end training using image labels only, and achieves state-of-the-art performance on fine-grained classification.*

Comment: Great summary. Just one point -- for the Bilinear CNN model we directly took an outer product of x and y, which would mean an identity matrix for M. Since x and y are the result of learned projections anyway, one can assume anything that a matrix M would encode can be learned end-to-end in the features.

Comment: I am stuck in the formula (,)==∑. Can someone explain it? How do we multiply for instance $x^{T}A$. The dimensions don't seems to match. I am not sure how to do this matching actually since x is 2d and M is 3d.

Comment: For each image, they are done separately. You can search for vectorization.

Comment: @EduardoReis it is not simple matrix multiplication. It is done by einstein summation aka einsum.

Comment: @GreenFalcon does bilinear functions works better than simple concatenation (of $x$ and $y$) and a linear layer? If yes, then why?

Comment: @Ritwik Sorry for my late response. To answer your question,  I can tell you that it highly depends on your task. I cannot tell you it is always like that. There is no proof to show that.